# Unable to build project with Appcompat library Android Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-support-library, android-appcompat

So I'm trying to run a demo using Eclipse and couple of support libraries in order to run this project. But to my surprise, I'm getting lot of build errors as displayed in the following error log.

> [2016-12-13 17:47:25 - RecyclerCardViewDemo] Failed to generate resource table for split ''
>   [2016-12-13 17:47:25 - RecyclerCardViewDemo] E:\Workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values\styles_base.xml:78: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'srcCompat' with value '@drawable/abc_ic_menu_overflow_material').
>   `

I have imported `android-support-v7-appcompat` in my workspace.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
```

I have almost spent two days to solve the problem but still no luck.
Please help!

Comment: why don't you use android studio?

Comment: Start using Android Studio as soon as possible. Check this. https://developer.android.com/studio/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html